# dynamic content for aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create some dynamic content for an aspx page and here is the direction that looks like it may work for me:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test123.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test123" %>

<%=_content %>
```

I have a protected variable in the code behind called _content that will supply the doc type and html contents which is coming from database.

Any thoughts or comments? Is this a good and safe idea? As long as I scrub the dynamic content.

Comment: Why you are using `Asp.net` then I think because of rich server-side controls if yes you might be using that only. It's difficult to maintain the post-back of dynamic controls. Though it is ok to use like above. You can use `Generic html controls` if you want to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use  for HTML 5 documents unless you had a reason to support older versions. So that code would not have to be dynamic.

I am not going to get into the reason why should or should not however your code would work just fine in Web Forms or MVC in terms of rendering HTML.
Here is some sample code behind

```
using System;
namespace StackOverFlowWebForm
{
    public partial class DemoForm : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
       protected string _content;
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
          _content = "<h1>My Dynamic Title<h1>";
       }
    }
}
```

Followed by a sample page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DemoForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="StackOverFlowWebForm.DemoForm" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<%=_content %>
```